# Is it ok to use 4k images as an Android-Layout background?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I used a 4k image as my root layout's background, it was running fine in my phone but very slow on a tablet, my profiler's memory indicator was high, everything worked fine when i removed the 4k image But i wanna know why that happened and how to use 4k images more efficient ?

Comment: 4 kbytes? Welcome to Android: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics

Comment: You can convert it to webp.

Comment: I think it's meant as, 4k as resolution, not 4k in filesize ;)

Comment: Yes I meant in resolution,

Comment: Do you mean by web like SVG file??

Answer (score 0):

**put image in asset then Try this code**

```
rootview.setBackground(getDrawableFromAssets("my4k.jpg"));


public Drawable getDrawableFromAssets(String img_Name) {

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream str = assetManager.open(img_Name);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(str);
    return bitmap new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}
```